# pyspark extracting specific value to variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below script.

I am a bit stuck with this specific piece:

```
datex = datetime.datetime.strptime(df1.start_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I can't figure out how to extract the actual value from the start_time field & store it in the datex variable.

Can anyone help me please?

```
while iters <10:

    time_to_add = iters * 900
    time_to_checkx = time_to_check + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_to_add)

    iters = iters + 1
    session = 0

    for row in df1.rdd.collect():
        datex = datetime.datetime.strptime(df1.start_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(datex)
        filterx = df1.filter(datex < time_to_checkx)
        session = session + filterx.count()
        print('current session value' + str(session))

print(session)
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you're looping over an RDD? Your for loop can be easily converted to `pyspark-sql` code which will be more efficient

Comment: I wasn't sure how to achieve the same without looping :(

Comment: Let me help you with that. What is `iters` exactly?

Comment: So during the day there are 360 blocks of 15 minutes. So iters would he set to 360 and each interation I increment the time by 900 seconds which is 15 minutes. So for each 15 minute block I get the total number of active sessions. Thank you for your help by the way

Comment: Why don't you use a 15 minute window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. I have converted your for loop in general. If you can get me more info on `iters` variable or the explanation of how you want it to work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions a F

spark_date_format = "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
session = 0
time_to_checkx = time_to_check + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_to_add)

df1 = df1.withColumn('start_time', F.to_timestamp(F.col(date_column), spark_date_format))
filterx = df1.filter(df1.start_time < time_to_checkx)
session = session + filterx.count()
```

Comment: this is so useful. Thanks! Do you know of any good websites or books where I can learn more about Spark dataframe operations?

Comment: @kikee1222 I just follow through the documentation. You should check out the blogs written by databricks.